# How do I install my github project to the root directory with composer?

Tags: php, .htaccess, composer-php, document-root

I'm making a request handler for php, which will route requests to specific files on the server. I have a `.htaccess` file that routes every request to `DOCUMENT_ROOT/Server/handleRequest.php`, which then handles everything else from there. To make this work, I copy the `.htaccess` file and `Server` folder to the root folder for my site.

I've been successful in getting composer to install my project to the vendor directory under `vendor/JakarCo/PHP-Request-Handler`. I would like all the files (at the very least, the `.htaccess` file) to be installed directly into the site's document root folder (one level above the vendor folder).

I am trying to use `oomphinc/composer-installers-extender` to set a custom path, and it's not working, and I can't figure out how to fix it.

The `composer.json` in the request handler is

```
{
    "name": "JakarCo/PHP-Request-Handler",
    "description": "php request handler",
    "type": "library",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "require": {
        "php": "^5.3.6 || ^7.0",
        "oomphinc/composer-installers-extender": "@dev"
    },
    "extra": {
        "installer-types": ["library"],
        "installer-paths": {
            "my/path/": ["JakarCo/PHP-Request-Handler/"],
            "path/to/libraries/JakarCo/": ["type:library"]
        }  
    }
}
```

The `composer.json` for the project that is including the request handler is:

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "url": "https://github.com/JakarCo/PHP-Request-Handler",
            "type": "vcs"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "JakarCo/PHP-Request-Handler": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

When I run `composer update` from from the site's root folder, it runs successfully (now with nothing to change). So I deleted the vendor folder and the composer.lock file and ran `composer install` and had three successful installs, of composer/installer, the oomphinc one, and mine. But mine is still going into the `vendor/JakarCo/PHP-Request-Handler`, when the `Server` folder and `.htaccess` files need to go into the site's root folder.

I suspect my problem is with `installer-paths`, but I can't figure out how it's supposed to be. Also, I'm probably not supposed to use `@dev` for the oomphinc version, but I don't know what else to put.

I'm experienced with PHP, but very out of practice, and am new to using composer and git.

Comment: Also, the request handler is a very early version and I know there's much to improve. If I can't get the composer installing to work, then I can do a manual copy-paste of the .htaccess and use namespaced classes for the other documents and make use of the autoloader. But that's stuff I'd rather do later.

Comment: Why you're installing it as dependency/library, if it should work as a project?

Comment: @rob006 I tried setting the type as project, but it didn't seem to do anything differently. The documentation really didn't clear anything up. I'm doing some more reading now, though. I don't really understand how it uses the different types.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

This turned out bad. Very bad lol. The composer.json from the request handler project overwrote the composer.json file that i was using to include it.

--

I wrote my own installer using https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/custom-installers.md as a guide, just copy-pasting what they had.

Important notes: The composer.json for the site I'm working on requires a pointer to the Request Handler and a pointer to the Request Handler installer as below. I tried to put the pointer to the installer in the request handler project, but I later read that the `repositories` part is only read by the root composer. That is, the `composer.json` file in the working directory from which you call `composer install/composer update`. Alternatively, the installer project can be added to packagist then the Request Handler project would be able to require it directly.

I had a hard time getting the installer to start working. That's because the `$packageType` passed to `supports()` in the installer is lower case, and the type i specified includes uppercase, so the `return $packageType === 'JakarCo-request-installer` turned into `return $packageType == strtolower('JakarCo-request-installer').

Another problem I had was composer telling me that the directory name returned by 'getInstallPath' could not be empty, when I was doing `return '/'`. I changed to `return ./` and still had problems. I did `composer clear-cache` then `rm -rf vendor` then `rm composer.lock` then re-rann `composer install` and now it is working.

This could all be much better, but for now I'm just needing the basic functionality. I will improve the quality of my code later. I'm new to composer and it's all kind of overwhelming, and I find the documentation hard to follow.

```
{
  "repositories": [
      {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/JakarCo/PHP-Request-Handler"
      },
      {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/JakarCo/PHP-Request-Handler-Installer"
      }
  ],
  "require": {
    "JakarCo/PHP-Request-Handler": "dev-master",
    "JakarCo/PHP-Request-Handler-Installer": "dev-master"
  }
}
```

So, the repositories had to be defined in the site project. Defining the repositories in the Request Handler project did nothing and then Request-handler-installer could not be found, because composer does not recursively function in that matter, unless your projects are on packagist, in which case you do not define repositories. Annoying, but workable.